# Having trouble adding together extracted integers from an HTML file

Tags: python

I am having trouble adding together the numbers in the linked HTML file (summing them).

I am receiving this error currently:

```
Line 26 b=sum(y)  typeError unsupported operand types for +: int and str
```

Here is my code

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
import re

counter = 0
added = 0


url = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Retrieve all of the span tags
spans = soup('span')

for comments in spans:
    print comments
    counter +=1
    #y = re.findall('(\d+)', comments)  -- didnt work 
    #print y
    #added += y
y = re.findall('(\d+)', str(soup))
print y
b = sum(y)
print b

print "Count", counter
print "Sum", added
```

**My desired output is something like :**

```
Count: 50
Sum: 2482
```

As you can see where I commented out my code - I attempted to add them like this originally. No idea why this didn't work.

```
#y = re.findall('(\d+)', comments)  -- didnt work 
    #print y
    #added += y
```

I am also not sure why this places the found numbers in a list

```
y = re.findall('(\d+)', str(soup))
```

Comment: you are summing strings. Try with `b = sum(map(int,y))`

Comment: So what's wrong? Did you get an error? And does `b = sum(y)` work?

Comment: @zetysz: I know, but then OP will get an error at `b = sum(y)`. But OP only said that he get an error at the comment part.

Comment: @zetysz: My question is: **Did OP get a error at `b = sum(y)`? If so, why didn't he mention it?**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to sum strings.
Convert strings to integers before suming, As Pynchia said, then print `b as the Sum` .

```
...
b = sum(map(int, y))
...
print "Count", counter
print "Sum", b
```

If you want to correct the comment part use:

```
...
y = re.findall('(\d+)', str(comments))
print y
added = sum(map(int, y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.findall):

> `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> Return all non-overlapping
>   matches of pattern in string, as a **list of strings**. The string is
>   scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found.
>
> If
>   one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the
>   beginning of another match.

This expression:

`y = re.findall('(\d+)', str(soup))` will return a list of all string matching your pattern `(\d+)` which is string of digits. So you have a list of strings.

Then,

`b = sum(y)` , will try to some strings instead of integers, which is why you got that error message.

Try instead:

`b = sum(map(int, y))` , this will convert every string digit in `y` to interger then sum them all.

**DEMO:**

```
>>> s = 'Today is 31st, December, Temperature is 18 degC'
>>> y = re.findall('(\d+)', s)
['31', '18']
>>> b = sum(map(int, y))
>>> b
49
```